# build tooltip for fxg button

Tags: apache-flex, graphics, flex4

I have a nice looking fxg button, to which I want to attach a tooltip- how do I achieve that without much hassle? (the spark button does this out-of-box, but is not very visually pleasing)

The examples I have seen on search is reverse- using fxg effects in the tooltip...

Thanks again for any guidance/ pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you use FXG to draw the skin for a Button, then attach that skin to your Button (either by CSS or by setting the skinClass style on the button when it is declared.)  That way you get all of the behaviors of a standard Button drawn however you like using your FXG.  You do this by creating a new ButtonSkin based on the default spark ButtonSkin and replacing the default FXG with your own.  You will then get the tool tip functionality for free.  Hope that helps.